# asp.net navigating between different views using angularJS in localhost with HTML (No MVC)

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, angularjs

What URL configurations are required in ASP.NET to get AngularJS routing to work?

I have tried many examples online and I can only get the when('/') route to show the appropriate view. Therefor, I conclude that it is a URL issue as to why the other views will not show up.

So there must be a URL configuration on the links, controller, or maybe somewhere else that needs to be configured.

Any help is appreciated.(personally, i'm about to just use jquery Load instead of angular...seems like more of a headache than for what it is worth.)

Thank you!

I have simply added an existing website HTML/JS files to my ASP.NET web application.

**Note:**
The other questions on this site with regards to ASP.NET angularJS are using HTMLCS files or MVC, so this question is unique.

[image]

[image]

tree
[image]

url

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These additional steps made it work.

Add #/ before the hrefs:

```
<li><a href="#/"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#/about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a></li>
<li><a href="#/contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a></li>
```

Add this locationProvider config before your routeProvider.

```
scotchApp.config(['$locationProvider', function ($locationProvider) {   
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
}]);
```